# How to prepare categorical predictor values that are comma separated but in the same table column?

Tags: categorical-data, predictive-models

I have collected a information on a bunch of movies. I'm especially interested in the actors, writers and directors and their relationship to the box office and rating of the movie. I'm still preprocessing the data. I'm using XLMiner Platform for Excel to do small scale analysis of the data.

My outcome variable is movie rating or box office and I have chosen to build a predictive model.

My question is, some of the fields in the actor, director and writer columns have multiple names in them. Transforming them to dummies isn't realistic (nor does XLMiner support that amount of dummies).

Would it be better to:

- Take the first actor/director/writer and remove the rest.
- Add extra fields such as Actor1, Actor2, Actorx, Director1, 2 and so on.
- Obtain a list of "popular" actors, writers and director and transform the predictors to a binary "is/is not popular actor"
- Some other method?

Any advice would be appreciated! English is not my native language, and I'm new to the analysis domain, so I couldn't figure out how to search for methods to solve problems like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said how you are going to parse these comma delimited fields into separate mentions for each name. I've assumed you have a method for doing that.

Given that, there is no single "right" answer to how to process this information for analysis as there are trade-offs with each. The chances are that any of the approaches you cite could be used. Here are some thoughts about them:

1) First mention: this would assume some sort of implicit ranking to the names insofar as the first name should be most "important" to the film with the last name being the least important. Using this approach would, in effect, reify this ranking, if it exists -- a ranking that could be verified with subsequent analysis

2) Adding extra fields: This might work as you could limit the count of fields for each role to a manageable number. My question is what would the resulting fields mean since "Actor 1" would be different for each film? The highly likely presence of many singletons in the categories would be a challenge to calibration. To the extent that there is considerable overlap across films, it would be a viable approach, e.g., insofar as "Tom Hanks" is mentioned across multiple properties

3) Is/is not popular: This would work but how is "popularity" to be measured? In my view, this approach would be a blunt instrument that loses the specificity available from retaining the actual names

Another suggestion might be to borrow a page from computational linguistics and create a TF-IDF measure for each specific name mentioned (the "TF") and treat each film as a "document" (the "IDF"). TF-IDF calculations are explained here, among many other sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

The obvious limitation with this approach is XLMiner, as you've noted. If you are able to step outside of the XLMiner framework, you would obviously have a great deal more latitude in your analysis. R or Python would be additional options. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do this (since they are freeware) but I'm not doing the analysis.

So, if you're stuck with XLMiner then the most viable approach I can think of is to agree that "adding extra fields" is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could use Python or R, but then I should ask the question again, asking for a Python or R-based approach! About method 2: Problems arise when there are 2 actors and I have 3 actor fields, same with the other predictors. These missing values would limit the amount of methods I can use to create a model. I'll try and use Python but I still have questions as to what is the most viable way to go.

Comment: And moreover, if a prediction is to be made and an actor is entered that was not present in the training set, then the method will fail!

Comment: If you go the R or Python route then you would be able to retain the granularity of the specific mentions and use the TF-IDF metric, as suggested. For the blank fields, one option is to plug in a text constant such as "BLANK" in lieu of a specific name. This field would then become it's own level in that factor.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. Are you referring to the validation or test data set?

Comment: I was referring to new data that will be scored using the model. What if an actor is entered that was not present in any of the validation, test or training data?

Comment: That doesn't invalidate the model, much less represent a "failure." You can leave any new names out until it comes time to recalibrate the existing model, bringing them back in as part of the updated estimates. Another approach is to "match" the new names to an existing name using a propensity scoring model or even a mahalanobis distance function. That could be onerous though and it's not obvious how it would be done efficiently.

Comment: We ended up splitting the actors, directors and such separately, then looked up their average gross movie income and summed it. This summation of average gross was the value we used to do our analysis on. This way we reduced any amount of actors in a movie to a single number. While this did not provide us with the expected results, it was still useful in our context seeing as time was a big constraint on our effort put into this.

Comment: The answer you provided was however described in our paper, and was one of the "would do next time" pieces in our discussion section of our extended abstract. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I'm curious how your analysis turned out. Would it be possible to share a link to an ungated copy?

Comment: I'm afraid both our paper and analysis are written entirely in Dutch; I don't know of how much use that would be to you! If you are still interested, please send me a PM (Not sure if that's possible haha) Thank you for your interest :)